# how to pass clientid and client secret in oauth2.0 in c#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

Here i am using external weather api to get the weather information.I easily configure my api in postman by passing client id, client secret,access token url and grant type. But i am not able to configure all this to my c# code.

Can anybody help me to configure above parameter in c#

Answer (score 1):

There are many libraries out there to help you with oauth apis. See [IdentityModel](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2) or https://github.com/titarenko/OAuth2 .